# Clean URLs when the URL contains a key/value pair

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I am having a problem with clean URLs when the URL contains a key/value pair.

Sorry for the length...but, thought it might help to understand my problem.

I am following this example (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRmlDeB7Ovs) His example works, mine does not.  I think that I may have to enable something else with my system...as I had to in the first line of my .htaccess file (see below) to allow mod_rewrite to work with php file types.

**Objective #1:**   This is working

Starting simple, I want my URLs to not expose the filename extension.

Before:

```
localhost/rewrite/handp/anyFileName.php
```

After:

```
localhost/rewrite/handp/anyFileName     <-- Good, no filename extension and the file displays properly in the browser.
```

I use the following rule to accomplish this:

```
RewriteRule ^([-\w]+)$ $1.php  [NC,L]
```

---

**Objective #2:**   This is **NOT** working, and I have no idea why?

Case #1: Instead of the following URL:

```
localhost/rewrite/handp/test.php/id=4       <-- This works: echos "value = 4"
```

Case #2: I would like to pass this URL:

```
localhost/rewrite/handp/test/4          <-- This does **NOT** work: echos "Hello"
```

For either URL, I want to echo 4 to the browser window.

I use the following rule to accomplish this:

```
RewriteRule ^test/([\d]+)$ test.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Note: The URL does display "cleanly" in case #2, but the key/value pair is not getting passed to the test.php page and therefore, echos Hello.

**test.php**

```
<?php
if ( isset($_GET['id']) )
{
    echo 'Value = ' . $_GET['id'];
}
else
{
    echo 'Hello';
}
```

This is my **.htaccess** file located in the folder "handp":

```
# I had to add the following line in .htaccess or enable it in /etc/mime.type.  I chose to put this in .htaccess.
AddType application/x-httpd-php         phtml pht php

RewriteEngine on

# Any filename with no extension, then get that filename and add on the php extension.
RewriteRule ^([-\w]+)$ $1.php  [NC,L]

# If you see the filename "test", slash, followed by some digits, then get filename "test", add on a php extension, and pass it the key "id" and the value.
RewriteRule ^test/([\d]+)$ test.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

**home.php** contains the urls that can be clicked upon

```
<?php
for ($ii = 0; $ii < 10; $ii++)
{
    // Example: localhost/rewrite/handp/test/4
    echo "<a href='test/$ii'>User $ii</a><br>";
}
?>

<-- Example: localhost/rewrite/handp/nfl_north_division -->
<p>Click <a href="nfl_north_division">Me</a> to go to the NFL North Division.</p>
```

**nfl_north_division.php**

```
<h1>NFL North Division</h1>
```

---

**This is my system**

Version of Linux

```
cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17.1
DISTRIB_CODENAME=rebecca
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca"

Note: Linux Mint 17.1, which is based on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
```

Version of Apache

```
apache2 -version
Server version: Apache/2.4.23 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2016-07-11T00:00:00

DOCUMENT_ROOT: /var/www/html
```

Version of PHP

```
php -v
PHP 7.0.9-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.9-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

**Do I have another configuration issue to address as I preciously had when I solved that by adding the first line in my .htaccess file.
I would appreciate it if someone could show me how to get Objective #2 to work.**

Thanks,
Mike